# irrational power of a matrix and sine of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real square matrix.

1. How can $A^\pi$ be defined ?
2. How can $\sin(A)$ be computed efficiently if A is also symmetric?

Note: For part2,  I know that $\sin(A)$ can be defined as  $sin(A) = A -\frac{1}{3!}A^3 + \frac{1}{5!}A^5 + ...$. Since $A$ is real and symmetric, it can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $Q$ so  $A = QDQ^T$ and we can compute $A^k = QD^kQ^T$ but I am wondering if there is something else we can use to compute $sin(A)$ more efficiently.

Comment: You can formally set up the taylor series for $A^{\pi}$ as you did it for $sin(A)$.

Comment: i have trouble defining  $(-1)^\pi,$  let alone $A^\pi.$ if $A$ is positive definite, then you can take the route of defining $\ln (A)$ first and exponentiate or you can define straight using spectral decomposition of $A$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is symmetric, you can define $f(A)$ for any function $f$ defined on the set $\sigma(A)$ of the eigenvalues of $A$ as follows: if $A = Q D Q^T$ where $Q$ is orthogonal, $f(A) = Q f(D) Q^T$, where $f(D)$ is diagonal with diagonal elements $f(D)_{ii} = f(D_{ii})$.